# SQL Server CTE implementation

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I'm writing a script as below based on my business logic, Please could any one suggest me, how can implement CTE (Common table expression)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpFirstTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpFirstTable

;WITH tempCTE AS ( select * from Table1  )      

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpTable
SELECT  * 
into #tmpTable
from table2  

Select * from tempCTE T1,#tmpTable T2 , #tmpFirstTable T3 where T1.ID = T2.ID and T2.ID = T3.ID
```

The above code format is should be as it is.

The **ERROR** which I'm getting is.

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.*

Answer (score 2):

Your `select` has to immediately follow your CTE declaration:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpTable
SELECT  * 
into #tmpTable
from table2  

;WITH tempCTE AS ( select * from Table1  )      
Select * from tempCTE T1,#tmpTable T2 where T1.ID = T2.ID
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

Also, it's becoming much more common to use explicit join syntax:

```
Select * from tempCTE T1 join #tmpTable T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, My CTE is between two If and some insert statements. I could say I have to use the CTE middle of the SP. that is my problem. Is this possible to implement that way?

Comment: The CTE is effectively part of your select (or insert/update/delete) statement.  They cannot be separated.  If you need to separate them for cleaner code, then you might use a table variable or a temp table instead.  At that point, you might be refactoring the wrong thing, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmpTable
SELECT  * 
into #tmpTable
from table2  

;WITH tempCTE AS ( select * from Table1  )      
Select * from tempCTE T1,#tmpTable T2 where T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is comparable to a view. However it is scoped to only a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement. If you want to use it in two separate statements you have to repeat the declaration directly infront of each of them.

Alternatively you can put the code into a real view and get reuse that way.